# How to know the types of windowing system, window manager and desktop environment of a Unix-like OS

Tags: linux, desktop

I was wondering what commands/utilities can be used in terminal to know the types of [windowing system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windowing_system) (such as X window system), [window manager](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Window_manager) (such as Metacity, KWin, Window Maker) and [desktop environment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Desktop_environment) (such as KDE, Gnome) of a Linux or other Unix-like operating systems?

Thanks!

Comment: So you want to know what's *installed*, what's *default* or what's *running*?

Comment: @bahamat: what is running. That is why I want to know if there are some system files or commands for me to check that. But if you also know how to check for what's installed, what's default, then I also would like to know. Thanks!

Comment: What do you want to do with this information? (Windowing system is at least almost always X windows)

Comment: @pjc50: different types come with different sets of applications. I need the info to decide whether an application is for mine.

Comment: For `desktop environment`, I came across `env | grep XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP`.

Comment: I think the only way to know what's running is to see what processes are running in your current session. As for what's installed, just check what packages are installed (but still you can compile from source, then apt database is skipped). As for what's default, it really depends on how you start your DE and your configuration. In general, there's no 100% sure way to test this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[From Ask Ubuntu.SE:](https://askubuntu.com/a/92948/769591) If you have `wmctrl` installed, `wmctrl -m` will identify **the window manager** for you.

[Thomas already mentioned](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/501473/258991) the `XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP` environment variable for identifying **the desktop environment**.

And [from this thread here in Unix & Linux SE:](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/355476/258991) the `XDG_SESSION_TYPE` environment variable can be used to identify whether **the windowing system** is X11 or Wayland.

Answer (score 6):

With difficulty.

There is no centralized system for keeping track of these things.

- On Debian-derived Linuxes you might try the `alternatives` system.
- You could query the package manager, and if you find only one Foo installed, you can be pretty sure which Foo is in use.
- You could try parsing the output of `ps`. Or equivalently of reading `/proc` on systems that have it.

Possibly the most reliable thing is to *ask* the user.

Answer (score 2):

One of the answers in the comments works for me in Kali (probably in other Debian-based distros as well)

```
env | grep XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP
```