# How to know whether Wayland or X11 is being used

Tags: linux, x11, wayland

I just installed the latest Kali Linux on my laptop which was based on Debian 7 (oldstable). I then dist-upgrad-ed the whole thing to Debian 8.

I've always wanted Wayland instead of X11, so I installed the necessary packages. Then created a minimal `~./config/weston.ini` configuration. Now, from the Gnome login screen:

[image: Login Screen]

I can boot to `Gnome on Wayland` or `LXDE` (among others). The previous with very limited success and the latter (LXDE) almost perfectly, though the panel needs setting up (I have to look up freedesktop).

Anyways, in LXDE, the GUI is more responsive than it was on the oldstable and possibly as fast when it was running Windows 7. I was pleased.

But I want to know if this is because of all the library/module upgrades from Debian 7 to 8 or from using Wayland (if I really am using Wayland at all). I skimmed through htop and found a `/usr/bin/Xorg` running and no process named "wayland". So which one am I currently running?

Comment: run xprop, this tool will work on xapplications running under emulation but not wayland or gnome-shell on wayland.

Comment: I guess I'm the only one to notice that while the OP said he was operating on debian, the screenshot he presented is clearly fedora...

Comment: Classical SE: An incorrect/incomplete, complicated answer gets 294 upvotes, and the simpler, correct, and complete one gets only 2. Getting the best answer at the top sure is a hard problem to solve.

Answer (score 543):

Obtain the session ID to pass in by issuing:

```
loginctl
```

That will show you something like:

```
SESSION  UID USER          SEAT  TTY
     c2 1000 yourusername  seat0    

1 sessions listed.
```

In that example, `c2` is the session ID.

Then:

```
loginctl show-session <SESSION_ID> -p Type
```

If you want all this on a single command:

```
loginctl show-session $(awk '/tty/ {print $1}' <(loginctl)) -p Type | awk -F= '{print $2}'
```

Use the one corresponding to your user name.

Refer to:
https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/How_to_debug_Wayland_problems

So, for me it is:

```
$ loginctl show-session 2 -p Type                                                  
Type=wayland
```

Comment: Thanks for the great answer. Please add that OP should run `loginctl` first to see the sessions.

Comment: ``loginctl show-session `loginctl|grep <YOUR_USER_NAME>|awk '{print $1}'` -p Type``

Comment: I think this detects whether the session you've logged into is wayland but it doesn't tell a script that's running in an x11 terminal that it's not in wayland.

Comment: According to [Fedora 28 docs](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/f28/system-administrators-guide/Wayland.html) you can also use `echo $WAYLAND_DISPLAY` which prints nothing if wayland is not used.

Comment: @DSJustice your backticks have been markdown'd. One can copy this:
`loginctl show-session $(loginctl|grep $(whoami) |awk '{print $1}') -p Type`

Comment: If one prefers verbose commands, the relevant command is `loginctl show-session 2 --property=Type`. Also worth taking a look at the [Fedora 29 documentation](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/fedora/f29/system-administrators-guide/Wayland/index.html) (that @robsch mentioned) which introduces the `xlsclients` (X11 Legacy Server Clients) command.

Comment: If you don’t use a display manger, this outputs `tty` no matter whether you use x11 or wayland.

Comment: @Devon And the same is true for `echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE`. So probably [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/559950/383543) answer is most fail-safe.

Comment: In more recent versions of systemd, you can also use `loginctl show-session self -p Type`.

Comment: `loginctl show-session $(loginctl | awk '/'"$USER"'/{print $1}') -p Type`

Comment: Since the release of sddm 2.0, it may cause the command in this answer to be erroneous. The following modified command will filter out ssdm from the session list:
`loginctl show-session $(awk '/tty/ {print $1}' <(loginctl|grep -v sddm)) -p Type | awk -F= '{print $2}' 2>/dev/null`

Answer (score 431):

> How to know whether Wayland or X11 is being used?

**on X11 systems**:

```
$ echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE
x11
```

**on some wayland system**:

```
$ echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE
wayland
```

*edit:* This doesn't seem to work in some cases. See comments & use [antismap's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/371164/27362) instead

Comment: What does it mean if this variable is unset?

Comment: Is there a way to show also the version of the running wayland protocols?

Comment: I am a Wayland user without a display manager. This outputs `tty`.

Comment: I am an X11 user without a display manager. This outputs `tty`.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/45537237/912144 for the proper way of checking this.

Comment: LXTerminal, when I execute: `echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE`, outputs tty! ...

Answer (score 97):

This works on Fedora and Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS:

```
loginctl show-session $(loginctl | grep $(whoami) | awk '{print $1}') -p Type
```

Comment: Power of pipes and unix philosophy. Nice.

Comment: /me mumbles something about `grep ... | awk`, but hey, that's fine.

Comment: A minor variation: `loginctl show-session $(loginctl show-user $(whoami) -p Display --value) -p Type --value` I guess this assumes a singe session id per user: I'm not sure whether there can be multiple ids.

Answer (score 33):

I like [Ayush's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/355476) the best, but thought I'd say that [Andreas's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/325972) can be done in one line:

```
loginctl show-session "$XDG_SESSION_ID" -p Type
```

You can additionally pass `--value` to drop the `Type=` prefix.

Comment: For me this failed with an error message: `Failed to get session path: Caller does not belong to any known session.` Apparently `$XDG_SESSION_ID` is not set on my wayland session.

Comment: XDG_SESSION_ID is not set for me, although other XDG_ vars are. (I am running wayland, on Ubuntu gutsy 20.10)

Answer (score 32):

The simplest thing to do is to check whether `WAYLAND_DISPLAY` variable is set or not.

Comment: Right, and then if that fails, check `DISPLAY` to see if X11 is being used.

Comment: This works even if you don't use a desktop manager. Other answers produce "tty". This reliable simple answer has a long way to go before it gains its rightful pole position.

Comment: @JoL A fresh install of Ubuntu 23.10 runs Wayland, but it sets `DISPLAY=:0`

Comment: @Andrew That's probably XWayland, which is why I wrote "then if that fails".

Answer (score 11):

Give the command

```
ps aux | grep gnome-shell
```

It will give the output

```
/usr/bin/gnome-shell --wayland --display-server
```

If Wayland is active.

Comment: And what if `wayland` is the default?

Comment: My "gnome-shell" process was not running with the --wayland option, but when I ran `ps aux | grep wayland`, I found that /usr/bin/Xwayland was running.

Comment: Often you have two `gnome-shell` processes: one used for gdm, and one used for the user session.  Often gdm's gnome-shell uses wayland but the user session's gnome-shell uses X11.

Comment: Xwayland is a process that bridges between X11 applications and the Wayland display server.  Its presence implies that you are running Wayland already -- but check the above caveat, it's possible Wayland is only used for the login screen.

Comment: `gnome-shell` only works if you are using gnome as DM.

Comment: A suggestion - I needed to run `ps aux` with the 'wide' option (`w`), otherwise output got cutoff and grep didn't read anything (`ps aux w | grep gnome-shell`)

Comment: Incorrect. Just depends on the gnome-shell defaults.

Comment: No, this doesnt work if Wayland is default.

Answer (score 11):

Tell which session type with POSIX-shell grammar and no sub-shell:

```bash
printf 'Session is: %s\n' "${DISPLAY:+X11}${WAYLAND_DISPLAY:+WAYLAND}"
```

Alternative handling all 4 states:

```bash
case $((0${DISPLAY:+1} | 0${WAYLAND_DISPLAY:+2})) in
1) session=X11 ;;
2) session=WAYLAND ;;
3) session='both X11 and WAYLAND' ;;
*) session='neither X11 nor WAYLAND' ;;
esac

printf 'Session is: %s\n' "$session"
```

Answer (score 10):

If you're running Gnome, run the command `r` in the <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> menu. It will restart the environment (`gnome-shell`) in Xorg (without losing windows and processes) but in Wayland it will give the message *"Restart is not available in Wayland"*.

Comment: Via Alt+F2 my Kubuntu 19.10 starts Robo3t, and via terminal i get "Command 'r' not found, but can be installed with:

sudo apt install r-cran-littler".

Answer (score 5):

You could run the `xdpyinfo` command. It gives information about your current X11 server (and display). It would fail if you don't have one (e.g. in a pure Wayland setting).

Comment: IMHO, that just means that your wayland session is not *pure* Wayland.

Comment: sure but the Q is "how to know whether wayland or xorg is used" for the current session... not how to know if there's a X11 server running

Answer (score 5):

The simple easy way to find out if you have Wayland or X11 is to open Settings, scroll down to About, and then scroll down to Windowing System, and it will tell you there.

In my own search for the answer to this question, after reading some of these "Answers," and finally finding out which I have through various Terminal commands, I found this much simpler way on my own.  I'm brand new to Linux and I've been going through a lot of trouble shooting issues, and this kind of problem often comes up.  It is extremely frustrating.  Why does everyone offer such convoluted answers instead of the simpler more obvious solution?

Comment: People sometimes prefer command-line solutions because you can script them.

Comment: When you get used to the terminal you will start to appreciate it. Apart from what G-Man wrote, you can also copy paste the commands from a website. You cannot copy paste a sequence of clicks.

Answer (score 2):

Open `xeyes` via <kbd>alf+f2</kbd> of via pseudo terminal.

Roll the mouse over the screen, if it follows your cursor, you are using `Xorg`, if it's just moves when you are onto the eyes, then you use `wayland`.

[image]

[image: warning] this doesn't work with `conky`.

Comment: nice idea, but this fails when using `conky`. as soon as your cursor is above the conky "window", they also follow it. especially when using big transparent conky "windows" without window decoration this can lead to wrong assumptions.

Answer (score 1):

if you want a visual hint, I wrote a simple GNOME Shell extension that shows an icon that tells you whether you are running Wayland or Xorg

http://www.fepede.net/blog/2017/04/gnome_shell_extension_xorwayland/

Answer (score 0):

No, I've noticed a pid called Wayland in htop, when I've switched to Wayland for giggles. Unless it's changed that's what one should see. Update: Here is a screengrab showing Wayland process.

[image]

Comment: I don't see a `wayland` process in your screengrab; the line you've highlighted is a `dbus-launch` process, starting a session called `gnome-wayland`.

Answer (score 0):

Well you could also just check if applications are running in their `wayland` native form:

```
cd /usr/bin
ldd $application_name | grep wayland
```

Furthermore, to check which binaries have `wayland` support you could try:

```
cd /usr/bin
find . | xargs ldd | grep wayland -B 55
```

The above is not really very clean but it works. You can further pipe it to a file and then use `vim` to navigate.

```
cd /usr/bin
find . | xargs ldd | grep wayland -B 55 >> candidates
vim candidates
# Use vi movement
```

The `-B` flag stands for before and helps to print the binary name.

You could [check this](https://grimoire.science/working-with-wayland-and-sway/#finding-wayland-binaries) for more details. This answer adapted from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43456936/determine-if-app-is-wayland-or-x-client).

Comment: Cleaner is this to list all programs and their X11 or Wayland dependencies: `find . | xargs ldd | grep '^[.]\|x11\|wayland'`