# RHEL8 - X11 forwarding not working

Tags: ssh, rhel, x11

I have two laptops, one running CentOS 7 and recently installed latest RHEL 8 on another one. The issue is that I am unable to launch any X program from RHEL 8 over `ssh -X` but reverse works okay (tried various, xeyes, gnome-terminal, calculator etc) . Let me elaborate

1. firewall on both the machines are disabled
2. X11Forwarding is set to yes on box the laptops by default (/etc/ssh/sshd_config)
3. from CentOs 7, `ssh -X root@rhel8` to login to RHEL 8 box.
4. from ssh shell, `echo $DISPLAY` shows `localhost:10.0`
5. from ssh shell, launch `gnome-terminal`. I expected this to be shown on centos laptop display but instead it shows on RHEL 8 laptop itself.

Interestingly, if I do the reverse, login to CentOS 7 from RHEL 8 using `ssh -X' and try to run any program in ssh shell, it is showing on RHEL8 laptop as expected.

Is there anything changed in RHEL8 the way X Forwarding works?

Comment: Do you have the same problem with programs like xterm, xev or xeyes or just with gnome-terminal? gnome-terminal is known to implement its own "application server", completely ignoring and breaking the X11 model, users' expectations, and any sane software engineering principles ;-)

Comment: every thing, even gnome-calculator

Comment: Are you sure you're running X11 and not Wayland on the RHEL8 machine? Please also try with some classical X11 app like xev(1), xlogo(1) or xclock(1) not just some gnome-*.

Comment: nothing working, not even xeyes. Also, I like to use gnome-terminal all of which works fine with CentOS 7. So kindly answer only if you have used RHEL 8 and solved this.

Comment: I have used RHEL8 with X11 forwarding, but I won't annoy you anymore.

Comment: If you can't run any X program, then you should double check whether you're running Wayland, as mosvy suggested.

Comment: well, as I mentioned, X runs fine, it's just that forwarding does not work. Read point 5. I also check /etc/gdm/custom.conf and I see uncommented WaylandEnable=false. Is there anything else I need to check?

Comment: Well, no, you haven't given any evidence of X11 running on RHEL 8. GNOME Terminal runs fine on Wayland, so point 5 means nothing. Wayland supports running X11 applications, so forwarding from CentOS 7 also means nothing. Try some of the methods in https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/202891/70524 to check whether you're running X or Wayland.

Comment: ok it's wayland. so X forwarding does not work?

Comment: You only need an X server on the computer running the ssh -X client. Running wayland on the remote side is inconsequential.

Comment: Also, gnome-terminal is kinda special, because if you are already running it in a local login session, it starts a systemd user unit that launches all local gnome-terminal processes, so you might be talking to that daemon for the ssh session.

Comment: see this:
[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12356425/error-cannot-open-display-localhost0-0-trying-to-open-firefox-from-centos-6/56734353#56734353)

Comment: see this link: [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12356425/error-cannot-open-display-localhost0-0-trying-to-open-firefox-from-centos-6/56734353#56734353)