# Am I using XOrg or Wayland?

Tags: gnome, xorg, wayland

I would like your help to find out if I'm using Xorg or Wayland. I followed a tutorial to install `gnome`, and before installing it, I installed `Xorg`, BUT, in the About section of the settings it shows that I'm using Wayland.

Does Gnome install Wayland? If yes, would it be safe to uninstall Xorg?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to know whether Wayland or X11 is being used](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/202891/how-to-know-whether-wayland-or-x11-is-being-used)

Answer (score 2):

GNOME Shell implements a Wayland compositor, so yes, it can run without X.org, and act as a Wayland display server. (It doesn’t *install* Wayland separately, it implements Wayland.) You can choose whether to open a GNOME session using X or Wayland when you log in.

If you no longer need X.org, you can uninstall it. Make sure you don’t uninstall Xwayland, because you’ll still need that to run X programs on your Wayland desktop.

See [How to know whether Wayland or X11 is being used](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/202891/86440) to determine whether you’re running X or Wayland.

Comment: @memezin If running `xhost -si:localuser:$USER; xhost` in a terminal emulator like `gnome-terminal`  still shows `si:localuser:some_user` (despite claiming that it has been removed), then you're running Xwayland, and consequently Wayland ;-)

Comment: @memezin Similarly, if even after removing `si:localuser:$USER`, doing X11 forwarding with fake auth data still succeeds, then you're running Wayland. `xhost -si:localuser:$USER; XAUTHORITY=FOOBAR ssh -Y localhost xlogo` will fail on Xorg but succeed on Xwayland/Wayland.