# DPMS does not standby my Samsung monitor

Tags: dpms

I own a pretty old Samsung BX2250 monitor, which I would like to be able to set to standby using dpms, like

```bsh
xset dpms force off
```

The expected result is the monitor going to standby. The actual result is, that the monitor turns black, then it says "Check Signal Cable".

I also messed around with

```
xset s off
```

as I read somewhere this interferes with `dpms`, with the result that the screen turns back on immediately. Using `standby` and `suspend` does not help either.

I own a GeForce GTX 960 graphics card, using the `nvidia-440xx` driver on a Manjaro, which uses x11 (by trying this: [How to know whether Wayland or X11 is being used](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/202891/how-to-know-whether-wayland-or-x11-is-being-used)).

I remember back some days with my old PC, it went to standby mode. Unfortunately, I cannot remember what I did to achieve that. Does anyone have suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to the question above was to use a HDMI cable supporting DPMS signals.

Note (to avoid the pitfall I fell for): The outer diameter of the cable does not indicate nothing about this. I tried 6 cables in total, the last one did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

DPMS in X11 has three phases (apart from `on`) which are `standby`, `suspend`, and `off`.  You might want to try running

```
xset dpms force standby
```

or

```
xset dpms force suspend
```

But be aware that it is not always possible to do all of these operations. You can check the Xorg log (might be somewhere in `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` for the current session, the `0` in there is a screen number and it might be different too) and see what DPMS features are actually supported. On my system when I check for that:

```
$ grep DPMS /var/log/Xorg.0.log
[    31.954] (II) AMDGPU(0): DPMS capabilities: Off
[    31.970] (==) AMDGPU(0): DPMS enabled
[    31.989] (II) Initializing extension DPMS
```

I can see that the only state my GPU driver supports is `off`.  That does not mean `suspend` and `standby` won't work, but rather that it will actually use the `off` action instead, even when I do `xset dpms force suspend` for example.

If, however, you just want the screen to be black, but be usable really fast after a key press or mouse event, then what you might want to look into is simple screen-saver. You must turn off "Quick Power-off in Blank Only Mode" for xscreensaver if you are using that, otherwise it will again just power off your monitor instead.

Comment: I checked my Xorg log and it said:
`$ grep DPMS /var/log/Xorg.0.log
[    13.568] (**) NVIDIA(0): DPMS enabled
[    13.572] (II) Initializing extension DPMS`
Compared to your output, my log is missing out on the DPMS capabilities line. Does that mean that the device/driver is not capable of any DPMS action?

Comment: @MPFelder Not necessarily, it might just be different log level that's used for that or the driver does not report it. You definitely have some capabilities there. What does `xset dpms force standby` do?

Comment: Nothing extraordinary. The screen turns black and the monitor displays the "Check Signal Cable"...

Comment: @MPFelder That is exactly what happens to me when the graphics card (or possibly display) does not support any other DPMS mode than `off`, same as I wrote in the answer. I think there is no other option for us other than screensaver blanking (just showing black screen, but still turned on) and `off`, which is not what you wanted. Sorry.

Comment: Thanks again @nert for your efforts. Please see my accepted answer for the disappointing solution.