# xdotool - Qt: failed to retrieve the virtual modifier names from XKB

Tags: qt, xdotool

I seem to be unable to make `xdotool` work. I'm trying to emulate keyboard shortcuts as <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd> via external output. I looked it up and `xdotool` seems to do exactly that, emulate keyboard strokes. But when I run my script I get this error:

```
Qt: failed to retrieve the virtual modifier names from XKB
```

when running something like this *from my code*:

```
xdotool key super+Left
```

But if I do the same, and others shortcuts as (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>), *from a common terminal* I get nothing at all as output, the process just finishes.

Obviously I have no expirience with this tool so probably I'm missing something but I can't figure out why and I don't see this error replicated anywhere.

Edit:

My "external output" is a python script that given circumstances executes different commands like this:

```
process = subprocess.Popen(command)
output, error = process.communicate()
```

I'm using Ubuntu 21.04.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by *"via external output"*. And, are you using Wayland or X11? - as it is `XKB` I guess X11 but ... https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/202891/140633 –  And do you mean `ctrl+alt+t`? (as in `+` between `alt` and `t`). Without it you should end up with a `t` in your terminal ~ before new prompt. It could also be useful if you include distribution and desktop you use.

Comment: I was using wayland, I changed to x11 and xdotool started working on my terminal. I will explain better my external output and distro editing my post. Thanks

Comment: Ah, OK. `xdotool` is made for X11. I am not updated on the status of similar tools on Wayland, but from the design choices it is (was?) not possible. It is a security measure, and for *me* one of the reasons I stick with X11 (screen sharing, screenshots, UI automation, automated input, scripted window management, ...). IIRC there are some tools that do *some things* - but require root access, which, well, is *not* something I want to do. Try searching the web for things like `Wayland xdotool` and similar.

Answer (score 1):

My problem was in the way I was executing the subprocess.

I changed my python code to:

```
subprocess.call(command)
```

and that did the trick

Comment: Without switching to X11?

Comment: after switching to x11!